# How do I obtain the directory of the current module in Node.js without using "__dirname" or "import.meta.url"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dry, es6-modules, dirname

OK, in Node.js, when using `module.exports` you'd use:

```
__dirname
```

To obtain the location of the current file.

For example, if you ran it from `x.js` in folder `y`, you'd get something like this:

```
blah/blah/blah/y
```

Now, I can't use, `process.cwd` because returns the directory of the *"root"* script, and because I'm using `import`/`export`, I have to settle for this hacky method:

```
// jshint -W024
import path from "path";
import url from "url";

const __dirname = path.dirname(url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
```

**NOTE:** the `-W024`, ignore code prevents JSHint from raising an ["Expected an identifier and instead saw 'import' (a reserved word)"](http://linterrors.com/js/expected-an-identifier-and-instead-saw-a-a-reserved-word) warning.

Also, I can't modularise it, using:

```
export default __dirname;
```

Because it'll return the directory of the module exporting `__dirname`.

Converting it to a function, like this:

```
// jshint -W024
import path from "path";
import url from "url";

function __dirname() {
  return path.dirname(url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
}

export default __dirname;
```

Doesn't work either, it'll still return the directory of the module exporting the `__dirname` variable.

My question is, how do I obtain the directory of the current module in Node.js without having to use `__dirname` or `import.meta.url`?

Thank you.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @AhmedMagdy I'm trying to obtain the directory of the current module in Node.js without having to use `__dirname` or `import.meta.url`.

Answer (score 0):

To use `__dirname` in node we need to import dirname from path module and `fileURLToPath`.
from url module and use __dirname as follows :

```
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
```

Answer (score -3):

If using `__filename` is allowed while solving this puzzle you can do this

```
const path = require("path");
console.log(__filename.replace(path.basename(__filename),""));
```